# What is the angle of the reaction force in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Question]

At what angle does the reaction force act on the tire in this case? The marking scheme says that the force is angled upwards, but from what I've learned, the reaction force is always perpendicular to the surface. 
The mark scheme answer is given below.
Thanks.

[image: Mark scheme answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) 'Reaction force' is a bad name. I recommend 'contact force'.

(b) "the reaction force is always perpendicular to the surface." This is clearly *not* the case; just rub your fingertips along a vertical surface and you will feel that the contact force exerted on them by the surface has both a vertical and a horizontal component. The component parallel to the surface – in this case the vertical component – is called *friction*. The component at right angles to the surface – in this case the horizontal component – is called the *normal contact force*.

(c) Your diagram and calculations look fine. Using the terminology in (b), $N$ is the contact force, $N \cos \alpha$ is the frictional force and $N \sin \alpha$ is the normal contact force.

Comment: Thank you very much. I completely forgot that normal contact force and the resultant contact force were different things.